# Need help learning to use lambdas more, like in the following method

Tags: c#, lambda

I've never used a lambda or linq before; but I really want to learn how to.  I understand Linq, I've used it to query collections with some very simple lambda expressions, but I see other coders using lambdas in almost every coding situation.  I don't fully understand them, and it's a little frustrating.

So I was hoping to get some help transforming a method I just wrote to use lambdas anywhere they can be used.  I'm not trying to optimize the method, I'm just curious where you could use lambdas in it, and if you could provide a brief description of why you used the lambda where you did I would really appreciate it.

I understand how to use delegates, and anonymous delegate, I just never use Lambdas; but I want to change that.

```
private string GetFileOutputPath(string filePath, string fileName, string fileExtension, DateTime fileTime, string fileTimeFormat)
    {
        string outputFilePath = string.Empty;
        string fileTimeString = fileTime.ToString(fileTimeFormat);

        //Create initial output filepath, before we check for dups.
        if (filePath[filePath.Length - 1] != '\\')
            outputFilePath = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}_{2}", filePath, fileName, fileTimeString);
        else
            outputFilePath = String.Format(@"{0}{1}_{2}", filePath, fileName, fileTimeString);

        //In the case we already have the file in the directory.  
        if (File.Exists(String.Format("{0}.{1}", outputFilePath, fileExtension)))
        {
            //Iterate through the directory until we find a file name we can use .. using the microsoft convention of "filename(1).txt".
            int i;
            for (i = 1; File.Exists(String.Format("{0}({1}).{2}", outputFilePath, i, fileExtension)); ++i);

            outputFilePath = String.Format("{0}({1}).{2}", outputFilePath, i, fileExtension);
        }
        else
        {
            outputFilePath = String.Format("{0}.{1}", outputFilePath, fileExtension);
        }

        return outputFilePath;
    }
```

Comment: An Lambda is just an anonymous method. Anywhere you could use a method, you could use a Lambda.

Comment: There's nothing in there that jumps out and says _"yeah a lambda expression could be useful here"_. Also, I've edited your question somewhat, as asking for tutorials is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inside your GetFileOutputPath function that really indicates the need for a lambda.  This is because there's no method or function in your code that requires you to pass in a function.  Lambdas are used whenever functions are passed into something as parameters.

If you want to get a better understanding of lambdas, perhaps it would be better to begin to build your own primitive version of some of those linq methods you're trying to understand.  Consider this function, which accepts a function as it's second parameter:

```
List<int> filterList (List<int> list, Func<int,bool> filterFunc) {
    var result = new List<int>();
    foreach(var entry in list) {
        if(filterFunc(entry)) {
            result.Add(entry);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

You would use it with a lambda like this:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var filtered = filterList(list, entry => entry >= 2);
// [2,3]
```

You can here see one great advantage of lambdas: you don't have to create the function before using it inside 'filterList'.  You *could* create the function first, but if it's a one-time use and very simple function, minus well just define it at the same time you're passing it in as a parameter.

---

**Edit:** *To address OP desire to really force the use of lambdas in his code.*

You use String.Format 6 times.  Your use of parameters is so varied that lambdas are not really advised.  Nevertheless, to satiate your curiosity, let's do it!

Here's two similar ways you use String.Format:

```
String.Format(@"{0}\{1}_{2}", filePath, fileName, fileTimeString);
String.Format(@"{0}{1}_{2}", filePath, fileName, fileTimeString);
```

All parameters are identical except for the first.  So let's create a variable that is a function.  We'll define it using lambda syntax:

```
Func<string,string> formatInput = 
    format => String.Format(format, filePath, fileName, fileTimeString);

// <string,string> means that the first (and only) parameter, eventually 
// called 'format', is a string, and that the output is a string.
```

So now you can just do this:

```
formatInput(@"{0}\{1}_{2}");
formatInput(@"{0}{1}_{2}");
```

And yes, 'formatInput' has access to your local scope, so it's aware of 'filePath', 'fileName' and 'fileTimeString', even though you don't pass them as parameters.

Replacing all your uses of String.Format with 3 locally defined functions, your code can look like this:

```
private string GetFileOutputPath(string filePath, string fileName, string fileExtension, DateTime fileTime, string fileTimeFormat) {

    string outputFilePath = string.Empty;
    string fileTimeString = fileTime.ToString(fileTimeFormat);

    Func<string,string> formatInput = format => String.Format(format, filePath, fileName, fileTimeString);
    Func<string,string> formatOutput = format => String.Format(format, outputFilePath, fileExtension);
    Func<string,int,string> formatOutputI = (format, i) => String.Format(format, outputFilePath, i, fileExtension);

    //Create initial output filepath, before we check for dups.
    if (filePath[filePath.Length - 1] != '\\')
        outputFilePath = formatInput(@"{0}\{1}_{2}");
    else
        outputFilePath = formatInput(@"{0}{1}_{2}");

    //In the case we already have the file in the directory.  
    if (File.Exists(formatOutput("{0}.{1}"))) {
        //Iterate through the directory until we find a file name we can use .. using the microsoft convention of "filename(1).txt".
        int i;
        for (i = 1; File.Exists(formatOutputI("{0}({1}).{2}", i)); ++i);
        outputFilePath = formatOutputI("{0}({1}).{2}", i);
    }
    else {
        outputFilePath = formatOutput("{0}.{1}");
    }

    return outputFilePath;
}
```

Even though locally defined functions don't shine in your example, I'm not afraid to use them if I think they'll improve readability and DRY concerns, and where a formal function or method is not prefered.  I'm guessing your colleagues aren't necessarily using lambdas just to show off.  They can very much make your code more elegant.  Even in the code I reworked for you, where lambdas aren't advised, I would forgive a coder for using them.

Comment: Right, see that's my thought exactly, there' nowhere in there where you would need to use a Lambda, and yet I see people using them in those situations anyway.  I think some people choose to use them just so they can have other coders see that they've used them.  But you missed the point of my question, I'd like to see where they can be used, not should or need to be used.  If you were lambda happy and you wanted to put them anywhere you could in this method that literally has no call for a lambda; where would you put one?

Comment: @DaTurk, okay, if you sort of want it forced, stand by.